# Swift: Can Alamofire be used to storing data to Google drive

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am a bit new to Xcode. I am trying to get the streaming data of an app and upload those data to an online platform, like google drive. I am just starting to learn a bit of Alamofire. I believe it can make a request from http and storing the JSON files back to the app. I am wondering can **[Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)**  be used to send the streaming data (as a .txt file) to the google drive?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad. We expect you to research this, try working with what you learned and then, if you run into a problem with your code, ask a specific question about a particular problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should to read more books, before ask such questions here.

You can use Alamofire to make requests to server - get or post data.

You can store data to Google Drive, using their API, but you need setup access to it:

- setup google account,
- implement authentification (OAuth) in your app for Google Drive.
- and then implement requests (You can use or not Alamofire for it) to Google Drive API.

I think it can be a bit hard for you. 
As alternative you can try to upload your data to Firebase Storage.

- Setup Firebase Storage (its easy) - get link for upload your data
- implement upload your data to this storage (You can use or not Alamofire for it)